# how convert single row transposed into multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

dynamically how to convert single row transposed into multiple columns.

[image]

Comment: they will always be when a maximum of 6 columns of being this way you can use the PIVOT

Comment: and if your "noofuser" values are dynamically, you could build your PIVOT-statement with dynamic sql